# Trigger applies only second

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, triggers

I have a user control with the following resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="tmp1">
        <Image Source="Resources/img1.png>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="tmp2">
        <Image Source="Resources/img2.png>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I tried to apply the template when a button is getting enabled with the following trigger:

```
    <Style TargetType="Buton">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource tmp1}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn1, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource tmp2}"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Nothing happends!

But listen to this: When I add a second setter as following:

```
    <Style TargetType="Buton">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource tmp1}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn1, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource tmp2}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-6"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The button changes it's template (and doesn't move at all - the margin is not applied!).

Can anyone tell me what causes this behaivour?

Comment: What is `btn1` .. I dont see that element anywhere ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a standard trigger to observe the "IsEnabled" property.
something like this should work

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="tmp1">
  <Image Source="img1.png"/>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="tmp2">
  <Image Source="img2.png"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource tmp1}" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource tmp2}"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>

  <Grid>  
    <Button IsEnabled="False"></Button>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Hope this helps.

Shounbourgh

Comment: Thanks, that did it.
Do you have any idea what caused the strange behaviour with the DataTrigger?

Comment: ...and DataTriggers will be used to trigger for data changes. E.g. you can bind the DataContext property of an element to a collection or a to a XML document. With a DataTrigger you observe containing data of the element and the Trigger will react. For more information (also DataTemplates) i can reference to the documentation of the msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx

Comment: But to your question (i have just recognized that i didnt answer your question :D, sry)...at first i'm confused with the usage of "btn1" in your binding in the Style...what ever...Margin is a property, which calls the Measure method of an Control which implicit means, that the control will be rearranged and rerendered...but this should be also happen for a style change...i have to say, its a bit mystical ^^..no idea until now